# Read permission error when adding disk Image to the Images Collection

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcutil

I'm trying to create and use custom images following [this guide](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/images#installinganimage) and I get an error.

```
$ gcutil --project=es-cloud addimage elasticsearch-0-90-2 gs://esimage/e4686d7f5bf904a924ae0cfeb58d0827c6d5b966.image.tar.gz --preferred_kernel=projects/google/global/kernels/gce-v20130603
```

It gives:

```
INFO: Waiting for insert of image elasticsearch-0-90-2. Sleeping for 3s.
+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
|      property       |                      value                      |
+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| name                | operation-1372347522289-4e0248e924631-f9512254  |
| region              |                                                 |
| zone                |                                                 |
| creation-time       |                                                 |
| status              | DONE                                            |
| progress            | 100                                             |
| status-message      |                                                 |
| target              | elasticsearch-0-90-2                            |
| target-id           |                                                 |
| client-operation-id |                                                 |
| insert-time         | 2013-06-27T08:38:42.289-07:00                   |
| user                | 338179480470@project.gserviceaccount.com        |
| start-time          | 2013-06-27T08:38:42.346-07:00                   |
| end-time            |                                                 |
| operation-type      | insert                                          |
| error-code          | 403                                             |
| error-message       | FORBIDDEN                                       |
| warning             |                                                 |
| warning-message     |                                                 |
|                     |                                                 |
| errors              |                                                 |
|                     |                                                 |
|   error             | PERMISSIONS_ERROR                               |
|   message           | Required 'read' permission for 'rawDisk.source' |
+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

I don't understand the error message.

I can read my disk using:

```
$ gsutil ls gs://esimage
```

gives

```
gs://esimage/e4686d7f5bf904a924ae0cfeb58d0827c6d5b966.image.tar.gz
```

I'm using gcutil 1.8.1.

Did I miss to add a permission somewhere?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue. I was launching this command from a Google Compute Engine instead of my local machine as stated in documentation.

Comment: If you launch the VM with the appropriate service account scopes (`--service_account_scopes=compute-rw,storage-full`) this should work.

Comment: Great! Thanks. You could add it as an answer.

Comment: After new testing, it still does not work with storage-full scope. Same error: Required 'read' permission for 'rawDisk.source'. Any idea?